# Inequality in theorem proof: Hausdorff dimension and projection theorem with energy integrals (Mattila book)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dimensional-analysis, hausdorff-measure

I am studying Mattila's book "Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension" and I do not understand how to reach the first inequality in the proof of Theorem 4.2. It is the following:

Let $2<s<\text{dim }A$ and choose $\mu$ with compact support contained in $A$ such that $0<\mu(A)<\infty$ and $I_s(\mu)<\infty$, where $I_s(\mu)$ is the energy integral of $\mu$. We know this measure exists due to what was studied in chapter 2.

Let $P_e: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be the projection $x\mapsto e\cdot x$ for $e\in S^{n-1}$ and define the measure $\mu_e$ in $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mu_e(B) = \mu(P_e^{-1}(B))$ for $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. With all this we have

$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e \leq 2\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_1^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e + 2\mu(\mathbb{R^n})\sigma^{n-1}(S^{n-1}).
$$

What I don't get is how to obtain the second term, I do understand all that follows and why it is necessary to "cut" the integral at $1$, but I cannot get the $2\mu(\mathbb{R^n})\sigma^{n-1}(S^{n-1})$.

$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{1}^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e + \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^1 |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e,
$$

so to get the $2\mu(\mathbb{R^n})\sigma^{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ I need to bound the second term, which is:

$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^1 |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^1 |\widehat{\mu}(re)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-1}^\infty |\widehat{\mu}(-te)|\,dt\,d\sigma^{n-1}.
$$

**Edit:**

Using [MathWonk](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/301562/mathwonk)'s suggestion I get
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^1 |\widehat{\mu}(re)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e \leq \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^1|\widehat{\mu}(0)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e\leq \sigma^{n-1}(S^{n-1})\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)\int_{-\infty}^1dr,
$$
which is not bounded.

I have been stuck with this inequality for about a week now, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Venturing outside my comfort zone, I would suggest  that one can reduce to $r$ living on a half-line and use the Bochner Theorem's "easy direction" to control the behavior of $\hat  \mu$ on the ball of radius 1. P.S. Your notation $e\times x$ for a projection map is a bit puzzling.

Comment: Thank you! I will study that theorem and try your suggestion. Also, yes, the notation was wrong, had a bit of brain lag while writing the question

Comment: Put more simply, $\hat \mu(0)$  =total mass, pointwise dominates $\hat \mu(\xi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using MathWonk's suggestion that $\widehat{\mu}(0)\geq \widehat{\mu}(\xi)$ for each $\xi$.

The idea was not to separate the integral between $(-\infty,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, but to do the following:

\begin{align*}
\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e &= 2\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_0^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e\\
&= 2\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_1^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e + 2\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_0^1 |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e\\
&\leq 2\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_1^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e + 2\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_0^1 |\widehat{\mu_e}(0)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e\\
&= 2\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_1^\infty |\widehat{\mu_e}(r)|\,dr\,d\sigma^{n-1}e + 2\sigma^{n-1}(S^{n-1})\mu(\mathbb{R}^n).
\end{align*}